# Calendar set() method not setting proper time

Tags: java

I'm setting the time on my calendar instance as following

```
private Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

public void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    int year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthOfYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayOfMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Calendar lCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    lCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute);

    Date lDate = lCalendar.getTime();
    if (lDate.before(new Date())) {
        return;
    } else {
        mCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute);
        setItemTime();
    }
}
```

However, on call to **getTime()** on both the instances of Calendar *lCalendar* and *mCalendar*, I'm getting the time at which the Calendar was instantiated not from the `hourOfDay` and `minute` arguments set on calendar instances. Also, if I call `getTime()` method again on the either instances I get the correct time.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: You might be getting the time you set using hourOfDay and minute in lDate. What is the problem

Comment: The problem is that I want to get the output in the form of Date object with hour and minutes as set in the method not the default hour and minute of calendar

Comment: Try using SimpleDateFormat to get the date in format you want.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The Calendar instance is not setting the supplied hour and minute arguments passed to it in set() method rather. I have no issue with formatting of the date. For e.g if I set calendar hours to 8 and minutes to 30 then it is not setting those values to its field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through Section , **Field Manipulation** [at Calendar Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Calendar.html)

Basically, you are setting fields not `time` and trying to get `time` but not individual set fields. As per documentation, Calendar `time` is not immediately updated after calling `set(...)` functions.

There, Read between the lines that ,

> The specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class.

So I guess, universal answer can't be provided.

Comment: Can you please explain more elaborately? Also, it is mentioned in the documentation that although the field value is set immediately but the calendar's time value in milliseconds is not recomputed until the next call to get(), getTime(), getTimeInMillis(), add(), or roll() is made. So the set() method does not recompute time value but call the to getTime() method does which is strange because the second call to this method does this not the first call. Hence, my question.

Comment: For your environment, first print the name of concrete calendar class using `System.out.println("Calendar Class Name "+lCalendar.getClass().getName());`, then we need to look at documentation of that concrete class.

Comment: I faced the same problem when i was setting a date several times in a Junit. The date in debug was still the old one until we call calendar.getTime.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I stuck in a `System.out.println()` before `if`. It tells me `lDate` has the new hour and minutes I set. If those are before the actual time (on my computer’s clock), `mCalendar` is not touched, of course, meaning it holds the time it was instantiated. At what time on your computer’s clock did you try, and what arguments did you give to `onTimeSet()`?

By the way, did you on purpose not use the `second` parameter? You may pass it to `set()` along with the others if you want. You may also want to call `lCalendar.clear()` first to get rid of the time it was instantiated.

Comment: Which set method did you use to set hour and minutes? Is it the same one I used or set(field, value) for e.g mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8).
onTimeSet is a callback method which is called when a user select time from a time picker. The first argument supplies hour in 24-HOUR format, second argument supplies minutes and third second which is not relevant to me, that's why I'm not using it. Also I tried using lCalendar.clear() method with no success.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, the only change was the sysout before `if` to know the value of `lDate`. So I used the 5-argument `Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute)` just like you did.

Comment: If not for race conditions or similar funny stuff, I believe your code should work (it obviously isn’t thread safe). You may want to check once more whether there could be an error outside the code you posted, and whether your if statement does what you want it to do (i always have to think twice when using before() or after()).